# How do I display a local pdf file in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS development. I can't get a local pdf file to display in UIWebView. I am setting up an array to hold the file names, then display them in the UIWebView. Any help would be appreciated!

From MasterViewController.m: (set array of pdf file names)

```
[mCommands addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]
                    initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Break",@"name",@"cmd_break.pdf",@"url",nil]];
[mCommands addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]
                    initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Close",@"name",@"cmd_close.pdf",@"url",nil]];
```

From DetailViewController.m: (display pdf file in UIWebView)

```
NSString *filename = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *detailURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL];
[self.detailWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: I honestly can't believe how many people confuse Xcode, the IDE, with objective-c, the language.

Comment: Oh great one, perhaps you can reach down from the heights of the ivory tower you so obviously occupy and help out a poor ignorant beginner.

Comment: First, a couple of things. #1: Is your file Actually being copied to the application's bundle? In Xcode, go to `Project->My Target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources`. If your PDF is not there, drag it from your project into that box. #2: Please Log 'path' before you load the WevView, It could be that the file name is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your code to load the pdf into the view semse right.

But the filepath is probably wrong. When you use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"pdf"];
```

It only needs the filename, it will append the type string. So you will probably get a result which ends with
cmd_break.pdf.pdf

Verify this with:

```
NSString *filename = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"url"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"pdf"];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

And yeah, as [Richard J. Ross III](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) pointed out. Your using the wrong key in your dictionary. The "name"-key will give you "Break" back while "url"-key will give you "cmd_break.pdf".

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't the problem that he's loading the value for the 'name' key and not the 'url' key?

Comment: Correct. Missed that. Edited.

Comment: Thanks to both of you...that was the issue (using "name" instead of "url"). I also changed the array contents to not include the file extension.